# create a loop: convert .txt to .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I try to convert all my .txt files in .csv, but I didn't manage to create the loop. 
The actual line for one file (which works perfectly) would be the following:

```
tab = read.delim("name_file", header = TRUE, skip = 11)
write.table(tab, file="name_file.csv",sep=",",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
```

And I would like to do that for all the .txt file I have in wd.

I tried the loop with, based on some reasearch on the web, but I am not sure it's the right one:

```
FILES = list.files(pattern = ".txt")
for (i in 1:length(FILES)) {
  FILES = read.csv(file = FILES[i], header = TRUE, skip = 11, fill = TRUE)
  write.csv(FILES, file = paste0(sub("folder_name", ".txt","", FILES[i]), ".csv"))
}
```

I'm on Windows system.
I would appreciate some help... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have the same problem before just like you, and now I made it works. Try this:

```
directory <- "put_your_txt_directory_here"
ndirectory <- "put_your_csv_directory_here"

file_name <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".txt")

files.to.read <- paste(directory, file_name, sep="/") 
files.to.write <- paste(ndirectory, paste0(sub(".txt","", file_name),".csv"), sep="/")

for (i in 1:length(files.to.read)) {
  temp <- (read.csv(files.to.read[i], header = TRUE, skip = 11, fill = TRUE))
  write.csv(temp, file = files.to.write[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the output inside the loop as well. Try this:

```
INFILES = list.files(pattern = ".txt")

OUTFILES = vector(mode = "character", length = length(INFILES))

for (i in 1:length(INFILES)) {
   OUTFILES[i] = read.csv(file = INFILES[i], header = TRUE, skip = 11, 
                    fill = TRUE)
   write.csv(OUTFILES[i], file = paste0("folder_name", sub(".txt","", INFILES[i]), ".csv"))
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer!
Though, it tells me it didn't find the object OUTFILES... so I should define it somehow before, right?

Comment: You are right. Check the edit I made. That should solve it.

Comment: Now I get another error. Maybe there's a problem with my text files? Could that be because they don't have the same number of rows?

'Error in data.frame(c(122L, 193L, 194L, 4L, 14L, 15L, 21L, 32L, 33L, 43L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 203, 206'

Comment: Differing row numbers should not be a problem - you are looping over the list of files. I see that your paste/sub structure is curious. Did you mean `paste0("folder_name", sub(".txt", "", INFILES[i]), ".csv")` ?

Comment: Indexing is needed in write statement too. I fixed the whole thing again. Try it now.

Comment: can we set a global option in R so that R never overwrite anything, and save conflicting things using e.g. the windows rule: `A.csv`, `A(1).csv`, `A(2).cvs`, ...

Comment: @AndaZ Different number of rows within the same data.frame is a problem (since it is not a tabular structure). Please check the file content of the file that causes this error. Perhaps the strings must be quoted because that the separater character is contained within the column contents. Please indicate which line of code is exactly throwing this error!

Comment: @Antti: it worked now, all my files became .csv, which is good! I really appreciate your help! The only thing is that I couldn't solve is to get a delimited table as I did when I did it for one file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input files always have at least 11 rows (since you skip the first 11 rows!) this should work:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")

for (i in 1:length(filelist)) {
  cur.input.file <- filelist[i]
  cur.output.file <- paste0(cur.input.file, ".csv") 
  print(paste("Processing the file:", cur.input.file))

  # If the input file has less than 11 rows you will reveive the error message:
  # "Error in read.table: no lines available in input")
  data = read.delim(cur.input.file, header = TRUE, skip = 11)
  write.table(data, file=cur.output.file, sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

If you reveive any error during file conversion it is caused by the content (e. g. unequal number of rows per column, unequal number of columns etc.).

PS: Using a `for` loop is OK here since it does not limit the performance (there is no "vectorized" logic to read and write files).

Comment: Thanks, @R Yoda! In fact, my original file starts the Header at row12. This is why I wanna delete the 1st 11 row. When I did it for a single file, it worked perfectly, but I can't find how to do that for all the files at once.
Antti helped me with his lines and I got the csv files, but not the delimitation.

Comment: @AndaZ Great to hear that Antti could help you. Please mark his answer as "accepted". What do you mean with "not the delimitation"?