# Loop: Convert many .txt to .csv in single directory [Using R]

Tags: r, loops, csv, dataframe

Probably a pretty simple answer but I've had trouble converting a bunch of .txt files to .csv files in a loop. I don't want to merge or append them, just convert 71 individual .txt files into 71 individual .csv files.

I was doing my best to refer to other questions with my code relying on this thread:
[create a loop: convert .txt to .csv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238391/create-a-loop-convert-txt-to-csv-in-r)

I was adapting it and this is what I have so far:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")

 for (i in 1:length(filelist)) {
  cur.input.file <- filelist[i]
  cur.output.file <- paste0(cur.input.file, ".csv") 
  print(paste("Processing the file:", cur.input.file))

  # If the input file has less than 11 rows you will reveive the error message:
  # "Error in read.table: no lines available in input")
  data = read.delim(cur.input.file, header = TRUE)
  write.table(data, file=cur.output.file, sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

However, my results are coming out with:

```
[1] "Processing the file: filename1.txt.txt"
[1] "Processing the file: filename2.txt.txt"
[1] "Processing the file: filename3.txt.txt"
[1] "Processing the file: filename4.txt.txt"
[1] "Processing the file: filename5.txt.txt"
```

and the formatting is all screwed up.

Any advice/ what am I doing wrong?

Cheers and Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic solution:

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
someVar <- lapply(filelist, function(x) { 
                            textfile <- read.table(x)
                            write.csv(textfile, 
                       file = sub(pattern = "\\.txt$", replacement = ".csv", x = x))
 })
```

You can always add parameters in the read.table and write.csv functions per your requirements.

Edited written file name per Gregor's comment

Comment: Maybe `sub(pattern = "\\.txt$", replacement = ".csv", x = x)` instead of your `paste()` for the written file name. We want to remove the old extension and replace it with `.csv` without inserting a space.

Comment: Thanks, changed my answer!

Comment: Thank Sumedh and Gregor! The combination of your comments worked perfectly.